# Why is git still pointing to .gitignore files

Tags: git

My `.gitignore` on a local repo looks like this:

```
api/includes/utility.php
api/includes/AppSettings.php
```

When I make changes to the above files, git seems to want me to track them and commit or else will not let me `git pull`

For example, on `git status`:

```
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
# Changes not staged for commit:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
#   (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
#   modified:   api/includes/utility.php
```

I have read several posts on Stack with similar issues, but I am not using wildcards in `.gitignore`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making git "forget" about a file that was tracked but is now in .gitignore](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1274057/making-git-forget-about-a-file-that-was-tracked-but-is-now-in-gitignore)

Comment: ["*A gitignore file specifies intentionally untracked files that Git should ignore. Files already tracked by Git are not affected;*"](http://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, the file is already tracked; it cannot be truly ignored until it is "untracked". You can "untrack" it with `git rm --cached api/includes/utility.php`.  Note that this will delete it on other people's machines when they do a `git pull`.